# How to create a OpenGL widget in Qt and VIsual Studio?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, qt, qtopengl

I'm trying to create a `OpenGL` widget using `Qt 6.4` and `VStudio 2022`, i have enable the `Qt OpenGL` widget under the modules, but i still getting a lot of compile errors:

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QOpenGLWidget::QOpenGLWidget(class QWidget *,class QFlags<enum Qt::WindowType>)" (__imp_??0QOpenGLWidget@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@V?$QFlags@W4WindowType@Qt@@@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl Ui_MainWindowClass::setupUi(class QMainWindow *)" (?setupUi@Ui_MainWindowClass@@QEAAXPEAVQMainWindow@@@Z)
```

I'm testing in a 'clean' project containing nothing more than a `OpenGlWidget` added trough QT Designer.

The includes i have added:

```cpp
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QtOpenGL>
```

My project configuration:

[image]

I have also tried adding, into `Linker -> General -> Additional Library directories`:

```
D:\Qt\6.4.0\msvc2019_64\lib;
```

And at `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`:

```
Qt6OpenGL.lib
```

But i continue getting the same errors.

I have installed everything in the `Qt Maintenance tool`, what i'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

`QOpenGLWidget` has been moved to Qt OpenGL Widgets module.
You must to link against both `Qt6OpenGL.lib` and `Qt6OpenGLWidget.lib`.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/opengl-changes-qt6.html#the-qopenglwidgets-class

Answer (score 0):

Which help from Qt Forum, I found that these errors were being caused because I was missing adding the `openglwidgets` module into the project.

After setting `Qt Modules` to `core;gui;widgets;opengl;openglwidgets` it compiled successfully.

It strange that the module `openglwidgets` is missing in the plugin window of `Qt Modules`, should be reported as a bug/missing?